# Understanding Python's conditionals and control flow with if blocks

Tags: python

Im a student that just likes to code so I started codeacademy. I have finished Javascript and now starting python. But my code is not working.

```
     #Make sure the function the_flying_circus returns True       
     def the_flying_circus(s):
if s == "yes":
    return "blah"    
elif s == "no" or "nai":
    return "blegh"
else:
    return "i do not understand"
```

help please

Comment: Fix your indent. Also, change `elif s == "no" or "nai":` to `elif s in ["no", "nai"]:`

Comment: Oh, please, not one of these once again! `s == stuff or other` __does not do what you think it does__! Just as in C or C++, unroll that into `s == stuff or s == other`.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Python uses it to define the code blocks (just like JS uses {})

Comment: Welcome to SO please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
def the_flying_circus(s):
    if s == "yes":
        return "blah"    
    elif s == "no" or s == "nai":
        return "blegh"
    else:
        return "i do not understand"
```

Next time please explain what is not working

Comment: Or ```s in ('no', 'nai')```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. The console says that the function should not take any arguments. I do not know what this means, so im stuck. if you don't mind please help me. thank you

Comment: What is the function definition and the EXACT code you are trying to run? If you define the function as in my answer and run the_flying_circus("yes") it should work

Comment: the exact code im trying to actually make it work is this                            
                                                                                                                   # Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True
def the_flying_circus(s):
        if the_flying_circus == s:
            return "blah"    
        elif the_flying_circus == s:
            return "blegh"
        else:
            return "i do not understand"

Comment: And how do you call that function? What do you get? What do you expect instead? What do you mean with the comment  "# Make sure that the_flying_circus() returns True" ? Maybe it is worth it editing your original question or creating a new one.